# ¿Cómo configurar OTP en Keycloak sin interactuar con su interfaz de usuario?

Tags: reactjs, api, djangorestframework, redis, keycloak

Estoy trabajando en un sistema que se autentica con Keycloak, que está en una DMZ y no tiene salida a la red. Mi objetivo es evitar acceder al formulario de inicio de sesión de Keycloak(o mejor dicho, su cliente, el que permite configurar a través de el codigo QR) y en su lugar hacerlo desde nuestro propio sistema (frontend o backend). Actualmente, nuestro sistema se conecta al cliente de Keycloak y configura OTP como una acción requerida por el usuario. Sin embargo, me gustaría encontrar una forma de configurar el autenticador móvil o OTP directamente en nuestro sistema, sin tener que interactuar con la interfaz de usuario de Keycloak. Una vez leí acerca de ingresar al código fuente de keycloak y customizar una SPI(interfaces de proveedores de servicios), pero no sé que tan viable sea esa opción.

Estoy buscando una solución que me permita configurar la OTP para un usuario sin tener que interactuar con el cliente o interfaz de usuario de Keycloak. Idealmente, esta solución debería ser segura y eficiente, y debería integrarse bien con nuestro sistema existente(DJANGO ,DRF, REACT, CELERY, REDIS, RABBITMQ, entre otros).

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.